# JQuery Ui dialog trigger

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using a Jquery UI dialog box

```
    $(".item-delete").live("click", function () { 
            $('#confirmDelete').dialog('open');
            return false; 
        });
```

In the dialog ok-event, I want to get the button (note that I am using a class item-delete and not an id to trigger the dialog) that triggered the dialog to open. How can I do this?

Comment: any reason to use `.live()` which has been removed? Check your console for error

Comment: @A.Wolff might be using a pre 1.9 version

Comment: @ArunPJohny ya sure, in that case live is not the issue

Comment: you won't get it unless you store the info somewhere... you can use `.data()` to do that like `$('#confirmDelete').data('opener', this).dialog('open');` then access it like `var btn  = $('#confirmDelete').data('opener')` it will store the dom element reference in the `confirmDelete` element

Comment: Unless he's using pre-1.7, `.on` is available and is preferred.

Comment: @Arun It works but with '$(this)' instead of 'this' in $('#confirmDelete').data('opener', this)

Comment: Indeed, there is no reason to use live. I'll modify to .on

Comment: @staccata my method should work... but then you have to use `$(btn)` to access jQuery methods

Comment: @ArunPJohny But in $(".item-delete").live("click", function () {,  'this' does not refer to the clicked button.

Comment: @staccata see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2GFwy/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny ok, you're right. this is still confusing me ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
$(".item-delete").live("click", function () { 
        var buttonObj = $(this);
        // buttonObj now contains the reference to your Button.
        $('#confirmDelete').dialog('open');
        return false; 
    });
```

Comment: Yes true, but I preferred to not do this, as defining a variable for this purpose seems superfluous.

Comment: But you will have to store the element reference to a variable because `this` contains the object reference until it is inside the scope of `.live` function here. `this` will loose its value as soon as it leaves the scope of `.live` method or enters into a new method scope. But `buttonObj` once initialized will store the value until the scope of the variable.